# Load an old version of google visualization library

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Google released yesterday a new version of their google visualization library - [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) - that is breaking some charts (in production, indeed)

Is there a way to load the former version of this library ?

Comment: Technically, yes, you can load a previous version if you know its version number.  I strongly recommend against doing so.  It is better to fix what is broken rather than rely on old code.

Comment: What is the old version number for Google Visualization? Using an old versions allows you to have the production up&running during the time you're finding the fix. With GV the changes go straight to your production system withtout any control from your side

Comment: It's hard to tell what the version number is since Google obfuscates them.  Loading v1.31 results in the newest version, and v1.30 does not, so my best guess is 1.30 is the previous version: `google.load('visualization', '1.30', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});`.  I strongly urge you to use this *only* as a temporary measure.

Comment: I'll tomorrow, can you put this as an answer so I can validate it ? (a prof. setup is from QA to PROD, with Google we go from one day to another to PROD and fixing in PROD is never a good idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the previous version with this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.30', {packages:['corechart'], callback: <callback function>});
```

Comment: Checked, this is actually not working an 1.0 version is use instead (check google of the loaded library in firebug or similar). So looking as just not possible

Comment: The version reported by the API is always 1.0 or 1.1, depending on whether you are loading a production or release candidate version, so you can't use the reported version as a guide.